# Stuck with writing a regex in python

Tags: python, regex

I am a beginner and stuck with writing a regex in python. I wrote this regex to check if there is match in the given input. Here is the code snippet in file named regexs:

```
regexp = '[-]?\d+(\.\d+)?[\', ][-]?\d+(\.\d\d+)?'
num = re.compile(regexp, re.IGNORECASE)
```

I am using this regex to be  tested in a test file :

```
def full_match(regex, text):
    """
    Gives a list of all complete matches
    """
    ans = []
    for match in regex.finditer(text):
        ans.append(match.group(0))

    return ans

tn = full_match(num, text)
print(
    'num:',
    '5,9' in tn,
    '5.0, 9.0' in tn,
    '-7.4159265 1110' in tn,
    '3.4.5, 1' not in tn,
    '1 2' not in tn,
    '3 - 4' not in tn
)
for match in regexs.num.finditer(text):
    if match.group(0) == '5,9':
        print(' match1:', '5' in match.groups(), '9' in match.groups())
    if match.group(0) == '-7.4159265 1110':
        print(' match2:', '-7.4159265' in match.groups(), '1110' in match.groups())
```

Output I get on executing the above code is:

> num: True False True True True True
>
> match1: False False
>
> match2: False False

Problem is I need to get `True` as the output for all cases. But My regex fails in certain cases .
Kindly help to resolve this.
TIA.

Comment: What, precisely, is the regex supposed to do? You've just posted a bunch of code that you say doesn't work, without saying anything about what would constitute "working".

Comment: question is not clear

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if you specify a regex with backslashes inside,
use a **raw** string (`r'...'`). Otherwise you have to double
the backslashes.

To match all your cases use the following regex:

```
-?\d+(?:\.\d+)* ?[\',-]? ?\d+(?:\.\d+)?
```

Differences to your regex:

- Change initial `[-]` to plain `-`. Square parentheses are needed when you
  attempt to match **any** of provided chars (not a single one).
- Add `?:` after `(`, in 2 places. I think, there is no need to match
  these "dot-digits" blocks as capturing groups.
- Change `?` after the first `(...)` to `*`. This way you will match
  such string as `3.4.5` (**two** "dot-digits" blocks).
- Change the "central part" to: `?[\',-]? ?` (optional space, then
  either an apostrophe, a comma or a minus (also optional) and again
  optional space).
- Delete `\d` before `\d+`.

Note that `-` at the last (or first) position between `[` and `]` represents
itself, so there is no need to escape it with a backslash.

Additional simplification: If you define the regex string as `r"..."` (delimiting
it with **double** quotes), you don't need to escape the apostrophe.
Then the regex can be:

```
r"-?\d+(?:\.\d+)* ?[',-]? ?\d+(?:\.\d+)?"
```

Comment: Thank you Valdi_Bo for your in depth explanation.